# How to use the text to be a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I already used docx-python this import let this [docx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuxNy.png) to text.

and this is my code:

```html
from docx.api import Document

dict = {}

document = Document('test04.docx')
tables = document.tables
for table in tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                print(paragraph.text)
```

Then I want to use these word, so now I don't know what's method can I do. I tried to use dictionary to be a place I can save these word, But it can't. 
So I need someone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want. Do you want the entire paragraph in a list by its own? Do you want it to be split by words? Do you want it to be split by characters? Exactly how do you want your text to be stored in that list? One example could be as follows:

```
string = "This is merely a sample string used for this purpose"
print(string.split(' '))
```

This returns:

```
['This', 'is', 'merely', 'a', 'sample', 'string', 'used', 'for', 'this', 'purpose']
```

The string.split() splits at desired input. I was splitting at spaces in the previous example, but you could split at '.' etc.

```
string = "This is a string. This string has sentences. Multiple sentences."
string.split('.')
```

Which gives you:

```
['This is a string', ' This string has sentences', ' Multiple sentences', '']
```

As you can see with this last example, you get an empty item in the list, since it split at the last '.' as well.

I hope this was somewhat what you were after.